# Turkish stem consonant alternation

Tags: phonology, turkish

I am currently writing a paper which draws on the characteristics of Turkish (or Turkic) phonology, and would like to know more about stem consonant alternation in this language. Specifically, will the k at the end of any (or all) the following words become a d when a suffix is added to the word?

balčyk
kıvrık

I will greatly appreciate your insights!

Comment: Did you mean ğ? I don’t know Turkish, but I’ve never heard of a /k ~ d/ alternation, whereas /k ~ ğ/ definitely exists.

Answer (score 1):

Words *balçık* and *kıvrık* get the stem consonant alternations with *ğ*:

- balçı-ğ-ı
- kıvrı-ğ-ı

To the best of my knowledge, there are no examples of stem consonant alternation for *k* changed into *d*. Meaning that, depending on the suffix to be added, either *k* remains unchanged, or it is changed into *g* or *ğ*.

Formally, in Turkish, words ending in *p*, *ç*, *t* and *k* get stem consonant alternations when a suffix starting with a vowel is added. The alternations are:

- *p* -> *b*
- *ç* -> *c*
- *t* -> *d*
- *k* -> *g* or *ğ*